# Lines appear to change thickness when scrolling

Tags: html, css

In the recent versions of Firefox, horizontal lines change thickness as the page scrolls on one of my pages. If I scroll the page until a line gets thin or disappears, and leave it at the position, it stays that way (scrolling itself isn't the problem, position on the screen is). These lines are generated in the border-bottom property of table cells. I'm trying to turn on must the bottom border of each td to create a horizontal rule between each tr.

IE, Chrome and Safari all behave.
In FF, if I change the border-collapse property to "separate", from "collapse", the lines behave, but I have unwanted gaps in the line, between each td.

Looking at the box model of the td element in Firebug, a 3px border-bottom is converted into a 1px top border and a 1px bottom border. A 12px border-bottom is converted into a 5px top border and a 6px bottom border.

I haven't been able to duplicate the behavior in jsfiddle, yet, so there must be some other property that is creating the artifacts. Therefore, I'm not too hopeful at getting a useful answer, unless someone *happens* to have already fought this battle and recognizes symptoms. I'm making my lines thicker and lighter in color to kludge this problem for now. The effect still occurs, but the eye doesn't notice it as much when the lines are thick.

I don't think we are allowed to post URLs, otherwise, I would post an example page from the live site.

Comment: so much theory.....atleast add a snapshot or code of what you mentioned - *i admit, i dint read everything* !! :)

Comment: @Ruddy : same to you fella!! :D

Comment: i read some of it like "I haven't been able to duplicate the behavior in jsfiddle". Like [codepen](http://codepen.io) says-  *demo or it didn't happen*

Answer (score -2):

give margin-bottom -1 it will be solve the problem.

Comment: @pranav : mate, problem is related to line *thickness* , margin has got nothing to do with it!! :)

Comment: Thanks for at least trying to be helpful. It didn't work, though. I have margin and padding set to 0. In the box model in Firebug, the only thing that isn't 0 are the top and bottom borders, and I'm only setting a bottom border. The fat lines that I kludged with are working ok visually, so I'm not going to spend a full day trying to get a jsfiddle to replicate the problem. Since no one has recognized this as something they've already solved, let's move on.